# neo4j apoc.load.xml get nested element value

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to import an xml-file with apoc.load.xml. Especially I'm trying to get the text in the label-element.
Here is my example query:

```
CALL apoc.load.xml('https://seafile.rlp.net/f/cf1f73f3cbdf413eb14d/?dl=1','',{}, true) yield value as xmlFile
UNWIND xmlFile._register AS register
UNWIND register._lemma AS wdata
RETURN wdata;
```

How can i reach the content of the label-Element ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the `label` elements, you can use an xpath (`/register/lemma/label`) in the `apoc.load.xml` procedure, like that :

```
CALL apoc.load.xml('https://seafile.rlp.net/f/cf1f73f3cbdf413eb14d/?dl=1','/register/lemma/label',{}, false) yield value as labels
RETURN labels._text
```